# Découpage en syllabes du mot « premier »

Tags: linguistique, phonétique

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi est-ce qu'on divise le mot « premier »  comme /pʁə.mje/.

Pourquoi le « m » et le « j » sont-ils dans la même syllabe ? Je pensais qu'il faut toujours séparer deux consonnes, sauf s'il s'agit d'un groupe liquide donc je dirais qu'on fait le découpage comme ça : /pʁɛm.je/. J'ai mis le e ouvert parce que la première syllabe serait fermée dans ce cas, mais je sais bien qu'on ne le prononce pas comme ça.

Est-ce que quelqu'un peut m'aider parce que evidemment j'ai mal compris quelque chose...

Comment: Voici un site qui donne quelques précisions : http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/P_b_division.htm

Comment: @Toto Mais ce sont les règles pour découpage à l'écrit, non ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Je pensais qu'il faut toujours séparer deux consonnes

Non, c'est loin d'être toujours vrai. Les manières de séparer les syllabes dépendent des langues. En français, je ne saurais pas décrire les règles détaillées, mais très souvent le français n'aime pas les consonnes en fin de syllabe.

Les [règles de divisions des mots](https://web.archive.org/web/20180305123526/http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/P_b_division.htm#_r%C3%A8gles_de_division_des_mots_en_syll) citées par [Toto](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29448/d%c3%a9coupage-en-syllabes-du-mot-premier#comment59853_29448) m'ont l'air correctes. En général, la césure se fait aux limites entre syllabes. Mais il peut y avoir des exceptions : des syllabes trop courtes pour être coupées, des découpages étymologiques et non phonétiques, ou des découpages qui correspondent à une prononciation historique soutenue qui n'est pas exactement la prononciation courante actuelle.

Par exemple, pour *exactement*, un dictionnaire donne [ɛg.zak.tə.mɑ̃], mais on a en fait plus tendance à dire [ɛ.gza.ktə.mɑ̃].

Dans *premier*, le son [j] n'est pas une consonne. C'est une [semi-voyelle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-voyelle), et même si on utilise aussi le terme *semi-consonne*, la semi-voyelle a tendance à être groupée avec la voyelle pour former une [diphtongue](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphtongue). Pour un français, il n'y a clairement qu'une consonne au milieu du mot, et cette consonne commence la deuxième syllabe : [pʁə.mje]. En poésie, pour atteindre le bon nombre de syllabes, on peut aussi dire [pʁə.mi.e], en transformant la semi-voyelle en une voyelle qui forme une syllabe séparée de la voyelle suivante.

Comment: Je me hasarderait même à supposer que [ɛ.gzak.mɑ̃] est une prononciation plus fréquente. Je doute en effet que beaucoup de locuteurs prononcent réellement un [ə] dans ce mot en dehors d'une prononciation très soutenue.

Comment: @Circeus J'ai plutôt tendance à prononcer [ɛ.gza.ktø.mɑ̃] ou [ɛ.gzak.tø.mɑ̃]. Si je vais vraiment vite, je peux peut-être prononcer  [gza.ktə.mɑ̃] pour faire trois syllabes, mais je n'avale pas les consonnes centrales et ça m'oblige à mettre une voyelle avant le [m].